# My script fails to parse items from a complicated webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a script in python using selenium to scrape different reviewers connected to each `item name` from a webpage. Few items have lots of reviewers revealed upon clicking on `see more` button and few do not have any reviewers.

I've tried to write the script in such a way so that it will get all the item links from the landing page then rove each of the links and then click on the `review tab` then on the `see more` button and finnally collect the reviewers and repeat the same until there are no more items left.

The main concern here is that when the script clicks on the `see more` button, It opens a new tab containing the reviewers.

[Link to the landing page](https://eatstreet.com/madison-wi/restaurants)

[Link to one of such item containing reviews](https://eatstreet.com/madison-wi/restaurants/glass-nickel-pizza-co-east)

[Link to the page containing full reviews](https://www.yelp.com/biz/glass-nickel-pizza-madison-9?adjust_creative=b0a8JvCAB1gC2Y2Y8DQf2A&utm_campaign=yelp_api&utm_medium=api_v2_business&utm_source=b0a8JvCAB1gC2Y2Y8DQf2A)

This is my try so far:

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = "https://eatstreet.com/madison-wi/restaurants"

def get_information(driver,link):
    driver.get(link)
    #collecting all the links connected to item names
    itemlinks = [urljoin(url,item.get_attribute("href")) for item in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"a.restaurant-header")))]
    for itemlink in itemlinks:
        driver.get(itemlink)

        #check whether there is any review
        revitem = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"label[for='reviews']")))

        if revitem and (revitem.text != "Reviews (0)"):
            current = driver.current_window_handle
            wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"label[for='reviews']"))).click()
            wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT,'See More Reviews'))).click()
            wait.until(EC.new_window_is_opened)
            driver.switch_to.window([window for window in driver.window_handles if window != current][0])
            while True:
                for item in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'ul.reviews div.review .review-sidebar #dropdown_user-name'))):
                    print(item.text)

                try:
                    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".pagination-block a.next"))).click()
                    wait.until(EC.staleness_of(item))
                except Exception:break
            driver.switch_to.default_content()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
    try:
        get_information(driver,url)
    finally:  
        driver.quit()
```

My above script can collect the `reviewers` names from the first available item containing reviews but it throws `timeout exception` error when it is supposed to go for the next item to collect the reviewers names. It perhaps happens because when the script `switch to default content` and try to repeat the action then the newly opened tab got unselected.

The below image shows how to reveal the see more button:

[image]

Comment: it's rather straightforward, but why not extract the links from the "see more" buttons and open them later? no need to keep track of new tabs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to close new window and get back to initial window, try to replace

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

with

```
driver.close()
driver.switch_to.window(current)
```

Comment: @Topto, You'd better also put `revitem = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"label[for='reviews']")))` in `try`/`except` or replace `presence_of_element_located` with `presence_of_all_elements_located`